# How do I access Metal Gear V Multiplayer?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I've played the prologue and part of Chapter 1 up to where I get access to the base.  When and how do I get to access the multiplayer part where I can raid other players?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplayer game modes, Metal Gear Online and Forward Operating Base, are not available currently. These modes are scheduled for release in October.

Source - [Forbes](http://www.forbes.com/sites/erikkain/2015/09/02/metal-gear-online-coming-to-the-phantom-pain-in-october/)

Edit - Apparently FOB is now available after Mission 22 and with online server connectivity.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that MGO is the only part that's delayed until Oct.